# Learnable LeakyReLU activation function with Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor, activation-function

I'm trying to write a class for Invertible trainable LeakyReLu in which the model modifies the negative_slope in each iteration,

```
class InvertibleLeakyReLU(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, negative_slope):
    super(InvertibleLeakyReLU, self).__init__()
    self.negative_slope = torch.tensor(negative_slope, requires_grad=True)
  def forward(self, input, logdet = 0, reverse = False):
    if reverse == True:
      input = torch.where(input>=0.0, input, input *(1/self.negative_slope))

      log = - torch.where(input >= 0.0, torch.zeros_like(input), torch.ones_like(input) * math.log(self.negative_slope))
      logdet = (sum(log, dim=[1, 2, 3]) +logdet).mean()
      return input, logdet
    else:
      input = torch.where(input>=0.0, input, input *(self.negative_slope))

      log = torch.where(input >= 0.0, torch.zeros_like(input), torch.ones_like(input) * math.log(self.negative_slope)) 
      logdet = (sum(log, dim=[1, 2, 3]) +logdet).mean()
      return input, logdet
```

However I set `requires_grad=True`, the negative slope wouldn't update. Are there any other points that I must modify?

Comment: You might want to use `nn.Parameter` instead of `torch.Tensor` (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html). Parameters are added to the list of parameters and will be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your optimizer know it should update `InvertibleLeakyReLU.negative_slope`?
My guess is - no:
`self.negative_slope` is not defined as [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10.0/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html#torch.nn.parameter.Parameter), and therefore, by default, when you initialize your optimizer with `model.parameters()` `negative_slope` is *not* one of the optimization parameters.

You can either define `negative_slope` as a `nn.Parameter`:

```py
self.negative_slope = nn.Parameter(data=torch.tensor(negative_slope), requires_grad=True)
```

Or, explicitly pass `negative_slope` from all `InvertibleLeakyReLU` in your model to the optimizer.